# How to resolve sonar guava issue?

Tags: spring-boot, sonarqube, guava

Could you please tell me how to resolve the following sonar issues.

guava-31.1-android.jar | Reference: CVE-2020-8908 | CVSS Score: 6.2 | Category: CWE-379 | guava - Creation of Temporary File in Directory with Insecure Permissions [CVE-2020-8908] The software creates a temporary file in a directory whose permissions allow unintended actors to determine the file's existence or otherwise access that file.

As I have checked the dependencies , we do not have such dependencies in our external libraries of our spring boot 3 application. So I have no idea why this error coming up and how to resolve them.

Expecting an solution to resolve this issue and may i know the usage of guava, this is first time i heard of guava.

Thanks